# What are the options for making a smooth login experience online?

Tags: authentication

How do you make it convenient to use the system for new users in the initial stages and move toward more permanent accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The lower the barrier of entry, the better. I always liked the [LibraryThing](http://librarything.com) model, where even the email is optional (although maybe it needs to be made clearer that that's the only way to recover your password).

Any supplemental information that the user gives you should provide some sort of value to them and be voluntary (age, sex, etc). Obviously, this is all my opinion - YMMV etc.

edit: [A quick collection of log in / registration anti-patterns](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2009/04/16/five-ux-antipatterns-to-avoid-when-designing-log-in-registration-areas/) that may be of help.